# Google Oauth2 refresh token error using python-social-auth

Tags: google-oauth, python-social-auth

I'm using python-social-auth and when I try to refresh my Google Oauth2 access token I get the following error:

```
[2017-02-15 14:41:00,089: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.tasks.test_login[169e5810-489d-4134-af8f-db3b80629fd2] raised unexpected: HTTPError(u'400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/paulozullu/dev/workspaces/wopik/wopik/tasks/tasks.py", line 1928, in test_login
    social.refresh_token(strategy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/storage/base.py", line 54, in refresh_token
    response = backend.refresh_token(token, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/backends/oauth.py", line 418, in refresh_token
    request = self.request(url, **request_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/social/backends/base.py", line 225, in request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 909, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

I use the following code to refresh the access token:

```
from social.apps.django_app.utils import load_strategy

w_user = WUser.objects.get(auth_user=A('username','xxxx'))
social = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(user_id=w_user.auth_user.id)
strategy = load_strategy()
social.refresh_token(strategy)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this problem? Having the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no. I'm implementing Youtube sign-in manually

Comment: I have the same problem and could not find a solution yet. But I think I know the reason. It is probably because your social_user.extra_data does not have a refresh token. I believe if you can login for offline access you can get  access_token and refresh token just like you can do it here: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground . But in my case there is no refresh token.

Comment: Any updates on this? Same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when calling `social.get_access_token(load_strategy())`. If you don't want to implement Google sign-in manually, I used this workaround which forces the user to re-authenticate to refresh their tokens.

```
try:
    strategy = load_strategy()
    access_token = social.get_access_token(ls)
except HTTPError as e:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('social:begin', kwargs={'backend': "google-oauth2"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

As yilmazhuseyin pointed above, the issue is related to refresh token not being present. You need to pass `access_type='offline'` in the parameters in order for Google to return the refresh token. This can be done by adding the following in `settings.py` for python-social-auth in django:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {
    'access_type': 'offline',
}
```

More details can be found in [Google OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient).